Learning from multiple datasets with the same dependent variable
I have multiple datasets exploring the same dependent variable. There is overlap between the six independent variables in the different datasets, but I don't have a dataset that has all six independent variables in it. I've done basic multivariate regression on each dataset to understand the relationship between the independent variables in each case - but is there some way I can bring together all the datasets or (all my regression analysis) to learn about the relationship between all six independent variables, even though I don't have a dataset that has all of them?
Specifically:
Dataset A: variables d, q, s, l... Dataset B: variables d, q, s, a... Dataset C: variables d, q, g, a... Dataset D: variables d, q, g, l...
(For technical reasons I can't have my dream dataset of variables d, q, s, l, a, g all in one place)
In case helpful:
d, s and g are binary variables;
q (3), l (21) and a (146) are all category variables and I've used dummy variables in my regressions (discarding one in each case to avoid collinearity). None of them have a straightforward mode so I don't think I can effectively combine A, B, C and D into a single dataset with a load of missing data and simply impute the MNAR data
I'm using Excel with the RegressIt add in, and I'd like to avoid using R/SPSS if I can. But if the only answer is to use something more powerful, I will find someone who can help me do it!
Any advice appreciated!
Ben
